# How to handle disconnections from wifi on an app in kiosk mode

Tags: wi-fi, 4.4-kitkat, clock, kiosk-mode

at work we use an android device (a Famoco device updated to Android 4.4) to register the employees clock in|clock out, similarly to a time clock.

We use Famoco to help ensuring our app is always on top and to update remotely the app without relying on the Play Store.

The device is connected in wifi to our server and our app upload the clock in and clock out to the server.

Sometimes it can happen that the device lose connectivity (we still don't know if it's a bug in the device wifi chip) so we want to ensure that in those cases the app promptly retry connection to ensure the correct use).

**The IT department normally does not have physical access to the device, so the app must know how to handle those cases autonomously.**

Thanks